# Regarding Extenders

Tags: logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

I'm having a hard time proving the following claim:

> Let $j\colon M\rightarrow N$ be an elementary embedding (between inner models) with $\operatorname{crit}(j)=\kappa$. Let $\kappa<\lambda$.
>
> Let $\mu$ be the minimal $\alpha$ with $\lambda\le j(\alpha)$ and let $E=\langle E_a\mid a\in[\lambda]^{<\omega}\rangle$ be the $(\kappa,\lambda)$-extender derived from $j$.
>
> **Then**, for every $\langle a_n\mid n<\omega\rangle$ (with $a_n\in[\lambda]^{<\omega}$) and $\langle X_n\mid n<\omega\rangle$ (with $X_n\in E_{a_n}$), there is a function $f\colon\bigcup\{a_n\mid n<\omega\}\rightarrow\mu$ such that for each $n<\omega$, we have $f"a_n\in X_n$.

I'm interested in a proof/hint for this claim.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think there is a bit of transcription error here ...

Comment: @Noah: I think you mean qqqqqqqq that there is a transcription qqqqqqqq error?

Comment: You should *really* learn how to write $\rm\LaTeX$ properly. Not just for this website, but in general for your mathematical future.

Comment: Edited. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: I've voted to reopen and fixed some formatting (and made a couple minor style edits). Next time you should tex your answer rather than mixing tex and copy-paste; there's a tutorial on this site.

Comment: Thank's for the vote Noah.

Comment: @Noah: Thanks. I fixed some of your $\rm\LaTeX$ (and a few typos that you missed).

Comment: Should i ask this at mathoverflow? it has been 5 days since this question was posted.

Comment: @Noah 0123456789